# Bootstrap tagsInput typeahead : How to exclude some input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

I've a simple html page with bootstrap-tagsinput and I have 2 forms. I would like to activate the typeahead functionality for some input fields but not all.

As I could see, when an html object is an input field, for example :

```
<input size="5" type="text" placeholder="hotel">
```

it is automatically 'overwritten' like this :

```
<div class="bootstrap-tagsinput">
    <input size="5" type="text" placeholder="hotel">
</div>
```

and I get the typeahead functionality through my script :

```
    $('input').tagsinput({
            typeahead: {
            source: ['Paris','Marseille',....],
            freeInput: true
            }
    });
```

However, I would like to exclude some fields from this typeahead and tags input behavior. I've tried some tweaks on the css and js files but it does not work.
Is there any simple way to exclude such fields ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class or id to the inputs you want to include typeahead:

```
<input size="5" class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="hotel">
```

And select that when you initialize typeahead:

```
$('input.typeahead').tagsinput({
               ...
```

Comment: Hi ioseph, I've already tested that class adding but it was still not working that's why I was quite confused in my first post. I've double checked all my scripts and I've found some javascript issues which disable some events...and now once fixed it works ! Sorry for my post and thanks for your help ;-)